# Using NLTK, how to get a dispersion plot of a list?

Tags: python, nltk

Using the NLTK imported data, I can call `text1.dispersion_plot(...)`, however I'm unable to use the `dispersion_plot()` function on a list of words/tokens.

I'm starting out with plain text achieved by:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(...)
```

Which returns a list type.

`text1` in the NLTK book's context is of type `class 'nltk.text.Text'`.

How can I use `dispersion_plot()` and other functions on my own text?

Comment: Take a look at `nltk.draw.dispersion.dispersion_plot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In using my own corpora, it should be loaded as:

```
myText = nltk.Text(...)
```

I can then use the additional class-based functions such as `.concordance()`, etc.